# Adding blank page

Tags: blank-page, scrbook

I am new in LaTeX and I am writing my thesis with it. My problem is when a chapter ends up to an odd number, automatically a blank page is added. But it doesn't work for an even page number I tried `\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage` but it makes two blank pages. 
I would be really thankful if you give me some hints.

Comment: the default behaviour is to ensure that a chapter opening is always on an right hand (odd) page, what behaviour do you need?

Comment: sounds like OP should remove an `openright` option (if it exists) and add the `openany` option to the document class.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need different margins on odd and even pages, to allow space for binding, change the document class option from "twoside" to "oneside".

Comment: I am using a template for writing the thesis. This is the document class which I am using: \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, headsepline, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, parskip=half, footinclude=false, DIV12, BCOR=5mm, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}   I don't mind that the first page of each chapter starts in an odd number. Could you tell me, what should I modify here?

Comment: There is no sided option specified in your current declaration, and I'm unsure what the default is. You can try adding the oneside option between the square brackets to explicitly specify this, e.g.
`\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 11pt....`

Comment: @DaveW The default in `scrbook`, as in the normal `book`, is `twoside`. Edit: and `openright`.

Comment: @ShahinMohamadnejad As David Carlisle mentioned in his comment, the default in book-like classes is for chapters to start on odd-numbered (recto) pages, so if the last page of the previous chapter was an odd page you'll get a blank even page, if the last page of the previous chapter was an even page there will be no blank page. Do you really want a blank page between chapters in all  cases? Would be nice if you edited your question to include the information about the documentclass by the way.